# Assign signer to specific signature form field

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm evaluating DocuSign esignature API (c# SDK) for an e-signature solution.

Our scenario is easy:

- single PDF
- multiple signers
- each signer has its own signature form field defined in the PDF

Is there a way to map specific signature form field inside PDF to specific signer?

What we already tried:

- Anchor text is working but it is cumbersome for our clients to position anchor text, changed its color so it is invisible. Also it is error-prone
- TransformPdfFields somewhat working but as I understand it is all or nothing it transforms all form fields and all signature fields are mapped to single signer (am I wrong here?)

Thanks.

Comment: Please upvote all useful answers (including those to others' questions). Please accept/check the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DocuSign, each field (SignHere fields, text input fields, etc) is owned by a specific signer or other recipient type. Fields are called `tabs` in the API.

At a schematic level, the object hierarchy is:
[image]

There are multiple ways to map signHere tabs to different signers and locations in your documents:

1. **Use a template.** You or your business person can create a template using the DocuSign web tool. Then your app can use the template id to create and send an envelope.

   The different signers are referred to as `roles` in the template. Eg `customer signer 1`, `internal signer` etc. Your app assigns specific names / emails to the roles when it creates the envelope.
2. **Assign the tabs (fields) to signers using the API.** The tabs can be positioned using absolute locations or via anchor strings.
3. **Use an HTML document as your source documents.** You can specify the tab locations in the HTML. See [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/creating-signable-html).
4. **Use a PDF Form as your source document.** If you name the form's fields consistently then you can use the DocuSign composite templates feature to have the form's fields belong to different recipients/signers. *I do not recommend this approach if you have control over the source documents.* But if you are give PDF Forms as your source documents, you can make use of them.

Comment: Thanks Larry I've already tried that and anchor string & absolute positioning are working, but they are hard to maintain.

 I'm interested in option 4 but it is not working. I'm using PdfTransformFields and TabLabel to map to signature form fields.

Comment: If you're having trouble converting a PDF Form to DocuSign fields, please post a NEW question. Include your API call and info on the form's field names.

Comment: Just want to add that I managed to do what I needed with Composite templates and PDF field transformation.
I'll probably need to flat all other fields but signature one before signing but that's OK.
Thanks Larry